# How to assign roles on successful registration?

Tags: symfony, controller, fosuserbundle, pugxmultiuserbundle

I'm using fos user bundle and pugx multi user bundle.
I've read all the documentation and I'm new to Symfony.
In the pugx multi user bundle there's a sample on every point but one: sucessful registration.

- Samples of overriding controllers for *generating* forms => ok
- Samples of overriding templates for *generating* forms => ok
- Samples of overriding successful registration sample => nothing.

Here's my code:

```
class RegistrationController extends BaseController
{
    public function registerAction(Request $request)
    {   
        $response = parent::registerAction($request);
        return $response;
    }   

    public function registerTeacherAction()
    {   
        return $this->container
            ->get('pugx_multi_user.registration_manager')
            ->register('MyBundle\Entity\PersonTeacher');
    }   

    public function registerStudentAction()
    {   
        return $this->container
            ->get('pugx_multi_user.registration_manager')
            ->register('MyBundle\Entity\PersonStudent');
    }   
}
```

The problem is with `->get('pugx_multi_user.registration_manager')` which returns a **manager**. In the [fos user overring controllers help](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_controllers.md), they get either a **`form`** or a **`form.handler`**. I'm having hard times to "link" those with the pugx_multi_user manager.

What code should I put in the `registerTeacherAction()` to set roles for teacher, and in `registerStudentAction()` to set roles for student *on a successful registration*?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Solution 1 (Doctrine Listener/Subscriber)**

---

You can easily add a doctrine `prePersist` [listener/subscriber](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html) that adds the roles/groups to your entities depending on their type before persisting.

*The listener*

```
namespace Acme\YourBundle\EventListener;

use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use Acme\YourBundle\Entity\Student;

class RoleListener
{
    public function prePersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entity = $args->getEntity();
        $entityManager = $args->getEntityManager();

        // check for students, teachers, whatever ...
        if ($entity instanceof Student) {
            $entity->addRole('ROLE_WHATEVER');
            // or
            $entity->addGroup('students');
            // ...
        }

       // ... 
    }
}
```

*The service configuration*

```
# app/config/config.yml or load inside a bundle extension
services:
    your.role_listener:
        class: Acme\YourBundle\EventListener\RoleListener
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: prePersist }
```

**Solution 2 (Doctrine LifeCycle Callbacks):**

---

Using [lifecycle callbacks](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#lifecycle-callbacks) you can integrate the role-/group-operations directly into your entity.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class Student
{
    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist
     */
    public function setCreatedAtValue()
    {
        $this->addRole('ROLE_WHATEVER');
        $this->addGroup('students');
    }
```

**Solution 3 (Event Dispatcher):**

---

Register an event listener/subscriber for the ["fos_user.registration.success"](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/FOSUserEvents.php#L137) event.

[How to create an event listener](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/event_listener.html) / The [EventDispatcher](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/event_dispatcher/introduction.html) component.

Comment: Quote of the link: `One important thing to notice is that a listener will be listening for all entities in your application.`... This implies that each time there's a persist action, *whatever* the persist entity is, this function will be called? If so, excuse me to say it that way, but it's a bit too much for just an action when registering a student or a teacher... that's kind of use a sledgehammer to crack a nut. Are you sure there's no other way?

Comment: well it's definitely a good way to go in terms of decoupling. the 1-2 little `instanceof` checks in there won't really slow you down.  you could aswell integrate the role-adding directly into your entities using [lifecycle callbacks](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#lifecycle-callbacks) if that sounds better for you. Well there are several ways, override the RegistrationController, fire an event on successful-registration, ...

Comment: That's it! I've got `Person` which is abstract class, and `PersonTeacher` which implements `Person` and `PersonStudent` which implements `Person` too. So I'll add custom "lifecycle" callback for each class, and that should do the trick. May I ask you to add your comment in your answer? This would help anyone reading this. Thank you very much indeed.

Comment: there you go ... I'll probably come back to your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19318065/how-to-pre-check-some-options-in-a-custom-form) regarding the "pre-checked" entity field-types later :) happy coding!

Comment: @nifr , you are great

Comment: 4 years later, I've given up on Php and that Symfony marmelade... it's one line in Django, easier to read, instant work, at the right place. I'll never go back to such horrible things. Thanks again for your answer.