# Assign a Role with FosUserBundle

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, pugxmultiuserbundle

I'm really new to Symfony, I'm trying to register a ROLE to a User with FosUserBundle but I can't manage how to do it. 
Actually I integrated also PUGXMultiUserBundle in order to have two different form for two different roles. 
Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance

--UPDATE--

I report my code in order to explain clearly. I create this files with the guide of [PUGXMultiUserBundle](https://github.com/PUGX/PUGXMultiUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md#7-using-the-user-manager)

This is my entity:

```
//C:\BitNami\wampstack-5.4.23-0\frameworks\symfony\src\Acme\ManagementBundle\Entity\UserGroundStation.php
<?php

namespace Acme\ManagementBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use PUGX\MultiUserBundle\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="user_GroundStation")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields = "username", targetClass = "Acme\ManagementBundle\Entity\User", message="fos_user.username.already_used")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields = "email", targetClass = "Acme\ManagementBundle\Entity\User", message="fos_user.email.already_used")
 */
class UserGroundStation extends User
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;
}
```

And this is the controller

```
C:\BitNami\wampstack-5.4.23-0\frameworks\symfony\src\Acme\ManagementBundle\ControllerRegistrationController.php
<?php

namespace Acme\ManagementBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class RegistrationController extends Controller
{
    public function registerUserGroundStationAction()
    {
        return $this->container
                    ->get('pugx_multi_user.registration_manager')
                    ->register('Acme\ManagementBundle\Entity\UserGroundStation');
    }
}
```

Sorry for the dumb question, but it's my first project and I feel a bit misplace.

--UPDATE--SOLVED--

I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19321146/how-to-assign-roles-on-successful-registration)
Sorry for the redundance of the question, I didn't find it by Google.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A way to assign a role, for example ROLE_ADMIN, to a user goes like this.

```
//Get the enity manager
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
//Get the user with name admin
$user= $em->getRepository("<your vendor>\<your bundle>\Entity\User")->findBy(Array("name" => "admin"));
//Set the admin role
$user->addRole("ROLE_ADMIN");
//Save it to the database
$em->persist($user);
$em->flush();
```

You can also set the role in the constructor of the User Entity class, which goes like this:

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->addRole("ROLE_ADMIN");
}
```

Remember that setting the role in the constructor means that's it is **not** saved in the database(unless your persist and flush) and that it is applied to every user.
If you have some additional questions please let me know.

PS: if you use the Sonata Admin bundle the user's role can be set with a form located in the Admin section

Answer (score 5):

This can be one with the console as well:

Symfony 2

```
php app/console fos:user:promote theusername ROLE_ADMIN
```

Symfony 3

```
php bin/console fos:user:promote theusername ROLE_ADMIN
```

You can also activate/deactivate and various other things with the CLI.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/command_line_tools.html